# How does this Toomre GI criteria have the period in the denominator?

Tags: gravity, mathematics, gas-giants

I saw this equation in a literature review recently talking about the Toomre criterion for gravitational instability:

[image]

Given here in section 2.1.1: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.06117.pdf, viz.

But I am not seeing how they got the period to be in the denominator from my own workings i get it in the numerator:

[image]

What am I misunderstanding here? How did they get the orbital period in the denominator ?

Comment: That $T$ is a temperature and that $\Omega = 2\pi/P$?

Comment: Oh true i should've used lowercase ${t}$ for time to avoid confusion, but i am not seeing how you got P in the denominator there.. Where did you get angular frequency to be 2pi over the period ? I have always known it as ${2\pi/t}$ @ProfRob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ Q = \frac{\Omega c_s}{\pi G \Sigma} $$
$$ \Omega = 2\pi/P$$
because $\Omega$, the angular velocity/frequency in radians per unit time, is $2\pi$ radians divided by the time it takes to travel $2\pi$ radians, which is the orbital period $P$.
$$ c_s = \left(\frac{kT}{\mu}\right)^{1/2}$$
Leads to
$$ Q = \frac{2\pi (kT)^{1/2}}{\pi P \mu^{1/2} G \Sigma} = \frac{2\sqrt{kT/\mu}}{P G\Sigma}$$

Comment: Oh its angular velocity not frequency. That explains my confusion! Thanks ! :)

Comment: @WDUK  Angular velocity is angular frequency. Both are measured in radians per second.